# ${var:=default} vs ${var:-default} - what is difference?

Tags: bash, variables

Seems both make absolutely same actions.

Empty `$var` returns `defaultvalue` in both cases:

```
$ var=
$ echo ${var:-defaultvalue}
defaultvalue

$ var=
$ echo ${var:=defaultvalue}
defaultvalue
```

Not empty `$var` return it's *value*  in both cases:

```
$ var=var
$ echo ${var:-defaultvalue}
var

$ var=var
$ echo ${var:=defaultvalue}
var
```

`$var` not set at all - returns `defaultvalue` in both cases:

```
$ unset var
$ echo ${var:-defaultvalue}
defaultvalue

$ unset var
$ echo ${var:=defaultvalue}
defaultvalue
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf It's not required.  The number of upvotes on the FAQ would illustrate that.  The lack of will to insta-close as dup by those having the _power_ substantiates it further.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They are similar only that `${var:=defaultvalue}` assigns `defaultvalue` to `var` as well and not just expands it.

Example:

```
$ var=''
$ echo "${var:=2}"
2
$ echo "$var"
2
$ var=''
$ echo "${var:-2}"
2
$ echo "$var"
(empty)
```

Answer (score 25):

**Positional or special parameters** cannot be assigned using `:=` way. See this example:

```
args() { v=${1:=one}; echo "$v"; }
args
-bash: $1: cannot assign in this way

And this:

args() { v=${1:-one}; echo "$v"; }
args
one
```

As per `man bash`: (**emphasis** is mine to highlight the difference)

> `${parameter:-word}`
> Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the  value  of parameter is substituted.

> `${parameter:=word}`
> Assign  Default  Values.   If  parameter  is unset or null, the expansion of word is **assigned to parameter**.  The
> value of parameter is then substituted.  **Positional parameters and special parameters may not be assigned to  in
> this way**.

Comment: And how can they be assigned then, for likewise use-cases? Different syntax?

Comment: Obviously, using the first type of syntax, i.e. `DOT='.'` and `${4:-$DOT}`.